# html website is overlapping and messing up on different resolutions such as mac etc

Tags: html, css, screen-resolution

I am fairly new to coding and had to make a html website for uni, this ive  tried position: absolute etc but still messed up any help please. sorry if ive done this question wrong or uploaded too much im new to this. Basically i want things exactly where i placed them but to resize on different devices and resolutions etc.

```
html { webkit-background-size: cover;
  moz-background-size: cover;
 o-background-size: cover;
 background-size: cover;
  }   

 /*this is the main title*/
h2 {
 color: White;
 font-family: optima;
 font-size: 100px;
 }
```

Ive tried commenting the code to help understand whats what.

```
/*this is for the logo*/ 
h3 {
text-align: center;
max-width: 100%;
}

/*this is the sub title*/
h4 {
color: White;
font-family: optima;
font-size: 20px;
border-width: 5px;   
}

/*centering text for all pages titles other than contact us*/
.text-center {
margin: 0;
padding:0;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
top: 50%;
left:50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);
}

/*centering text for contact us*/
.text-center2 {
margin: 0;
padding:0;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
top: 30%;
left:50%;
transform: translateX(-50%) translateY(-50%);

}

/*icons to take you to other pages*/
.material-icons {
color: white;
font-size: 48px;  
}

/* When moving the mouse over the  button, adds tomato color */
.material-icons:hover {
color: tomato;
 }

 /*left text box title*/
.head-text h1 {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 25px;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
top: 10%;
left:7%;
transform: translateX(-10%) translateY(-10%);
color: White;
}


/*right text box title*/
.head-text h5 {
 font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 25px;
margin: 0;
padding:0;
text-align: center;
position: absolute;
top: 12%;
left:70%;
transform: translateX(-10%) translateY(-10%);
color: White;
 }

 
  /*left text box on pages*/
.Body-Text p {
font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
font-style: normal;
font-size: 20px;
top: 15%;
left: 1%;
width: 30%;
position: absolute;
z-index: 1;
visibility: show;
color: white;
border: 2px solid white;
background-color: grey;
}
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Absolute positioning is a **very** poor method of laying out webpages. It is extremely inflexible and there are much better and more responsive options. Check out [**LearnLayout.com**](http://learnlayout.com/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use media queries to set different style rules for different resolutions.
Give this a read, hopefully it should help you understand how to implement them.
https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp

Answer (score 0):

To make an HTML page responsive(*responsive means it works pretty fine and cool on all devices of all sizes*). It is not possible by `absolute positioning`.
 **1)** You have to use media queries [e.g. `@ media all width` or e.g `@import url("googleimage123.com`")]
**2)** The language Bootstrap is used for this. Its just like HTml and css. With Bootstrap you can Build fast, responsive sites. Quickly design and customize responsive mobile-first sites. 
Here are some links to learn these:
To learn Bootstrap: https://www.w3schools.com/bootstrap/  
To learn to use Media Queries in Css: https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp  
To learn any computer/ programming language, or to get help regarding any issue related to them, I would prefer you to go along with `w3schools.com` 
***Good luck and have fun through your coding journey!***